# reading SharePoint list filter out the data in Power Apps

Tags: powerapps

I have below list in SharePoint and I need to display the result in PowerApps.  When shift overwrite is y and date and time are the same with the record with 'n', it will replace that shift Overwrite one is n record.
Not sure how to filter it out, need some help.

SharePoint List:

```
Date                Time          Name                 Shift Overwrite
=======             ====        ===========            ===============
09/01/2022          04:00       White Chessman         n
09/01/2022          04:00       Kim Lee                y
09/01/2022          20:00       Tom Shoes              n
09/02/2022          04:00       John Smith             y
09/02/2022          04:00       Kim Lee                n
09/02/2022          20:00       White Chessman         n
09/03/2022          04:00       Kim Lee                n

Query result want in Power Apps:

Date                Time          Name                 Shift Overwrite
=======             ====        ===========            ===============
09/01/2022          04:00       Kim Lee                y
09/01/2022          20:00       Tom Shoes              n
09/02/2022          04:00       John Smith             y
09/02/2022          20:00       White Chessman         n
09/03/2022          04:00       Kim Lee                n
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to filter Kim Lee (as static) as you did not mentioned any other condition

```
Filter(SharePointList, Name <> "Kim Lee")
```

SharePointList--> is  your datasource name

Comment: Thanks, it is not what I want, thanks!